# Why does pdf of arange function have normal distribution?

Tags: python

`arange` works on stepwise incrementing values and is not random function then why does it give a random distribution?

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.001)
plt.plot(x, norm.pdf(x))
```

I expect a uniform distribution

Comment: However if I do, values=np.random.uniform(0,5,100000)
x = np.arange(100000)
plt.plot(x, umang.expon.pdf(values)) it gives uniform distribution

Answer (score 0):

The library `scipy.stats.norm` provides functionality of Normal Distribution, not Uniform distribution. Meaning when you apply the probability density function (pdf), you are not applying a constant function, but something else entirely (also knowns as the Bell curve):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

So in the end what you are seeing are points between (-3, 3) visualised on the probability density function of Normal distribution. If you want to see Uniform distribution:

```
from scipy.stats import uniform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.001)
plt.plot(x, uniform.pdf(x))
```

But that is just a very fancy way to draw a constant line.